# Tracking social shares -- share not tracking

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I have set up a hidden page on my site and set up some buttons to attempt to test out pushing to the dataLayer. I have confirmed that my gtm is working,as I have a single record of the google +1 button that I had done the other day, so I can confirm that my credentials are properly set up. The problem I'm having is that when attempting to track, in this case an event (the action of pushing the button) I'm not seeing anything in analytics the following day.

```
<button class="js_test_share">test</button>
```

javascript::

```
    $('.js_test_share').on('click',function(){
     console.log('button clicked');

     dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'socialInt', 
        'socialNetwork': 'Facebook', 
        'socialAction': 'Share', 
        'socialTarget': 'https://reddit.com'
    });

});
```

The associated macros are set up in google tag manager, and upon pushing the button my dataLayer does reflect it

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, push: function]0:
  Object1: 
  Object2: 
  Object3: 
    Object
      event:"socialInt"
      socialAction:"Share"
      socialNetwork: "Facebook"
      socialTarget: "https://reddit.com
      "__proto__: Objectlength: 4push: function (){var b=[].slice.call(arguments,0);d.apply(a,b);for(vb.push.apply(vb,b);300<this.length;)this.shift();return Eb()}
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

The event in gtm is set up to listen for socialInt. Aside from pushing to the dataLayer is there a step I'm missing to facilitate this making it's way to my analytics?

Comment: I figured it out! In case any one is curious, I missed a step, that was not mentioned in the tutorial I was following, that you need to publish the new changes in order for google tag manager to fire.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! In case any one is curious, I missed a step, that was not mentioned in the tutorial I was following, that you need to publish the new changes in order for google tag manager to fire.